# Как получить JSON Get запроса при помощи Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, okhttp

Какой тип должен быть у ResponseObject, чтобы можно было получить любой ответ и потом его отобразить не парся?

Создаю интерфейс:

```
interface GitHubService {
    @GET("products")
    Call<ResObject> repoContributors();


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://somepath.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

Выполняю запрос:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        GitHubService gitHubService = GitHubService.retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
        final Call<ResponseObject> call =
                gitHubService.repoContributors();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseObject> call, Response<ResponseObject> response) {
                final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText(response.body().toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseObject> call, Throwable t) {
                final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText("Something went wrong: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте задать тип `JsonElement` [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25477954/3212712):

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {...});
```

далее в onResponse:

```
JsonObject jsonObj = response.body().getAsJsonObject();
String strObj = response.body().toString();
```

---

Ещё вариант - добавить Interceptor, в коем вы получаете непреобразованный ещё ответ

```
public static class MyInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        Log.d(TAG, "response.body().string(): " + response.body().string());

        return response;
    }
}
```

Его надо добавить в OkHttpClient, коий надо добавить в Retrofit:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor())
        .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        //остальное
        .build();
```

Comment: Первый вариант не пробовал, а второй - точно работает

Comment: первый тоже работает как швейцарские часики